# Sequelize - find item in column of array

Tags: arrays, node.js, field, sequelize.js

I have a column/field in a table which is basically a comma separated items. I am trying to search if one of the item is there in the many list of comma separated items. I am doing this with sequelize and it is throwing up on me. I am using this syntax and it say its wrong:

```
findOne({
            where: {
                new_hooks: {
                    $contains: [myvaiablehere]
                }
            }
        })
```

new_hooks is the field which is an array stored as a comma separated items list. A text search inside this field is also fine since these items are unique

Comment: Syntax looks OK. What DB are you using? Postgres?

Comment: No mysql with sequelize

Answer (score 4):

you can try this code:

```
arrayColumn: { [Op.contains]: ["1"] }
```

with `Op` is exported from `sequelize`

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i used

`flag: { [Op.contains]: "{Brazil}" }`

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you check in the docks about `$contains`, you'll notice it's for the `PG array contains operator` - that is, it's a postgres specific feature. So, you shouldn't use it. Try `$like` instead:

```
findOne({
    where: {
        new_hooks: {
            $like: ['%' + myvaiablehere + '%']
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Let me try this.